# Sublime Text Case insensitive Highlight multiple words on double click

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When you double click or just highlight a word in sublime it matches the case. is there any way to ignore the case on highlighting a word?

[image: Highlighter 'user' but 'User' is not highlighted]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not. The behavior of this feature seems to be hard-coded, and is not accessible via the API or the documented preferences. Changing the options in the `Find` or `Find and Replace` search functions doesn't seem to have any effect, either. Even the color of the outline box can't be changed.

Comment: Well, that's bad news. But still thank you for your answer!